# Heroku FAIL building a MERN stack web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

its not the first time i tried to push a MERN stack app to production. but this time i have no idea why it gives this error. as i tried to delete `package-lock.json` and re install via `npm install` but nothing worked.

i don't even know what info to provide you to help me.

```
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_832b2981fe399119f98e4a5349de3b9b/gh/react/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn
       npm ERR! code ENOENT
       npm ERR! errno -2
       npm ERR! syscall rename
       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/build_832b2981fe399119f98e4a5349de3b9b/gh/react/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn' -> '/tmp/build_832b2981fe399119f98e4a5349de3b9b/gh/react/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/.acorn.DELETE'
       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
       npm ERR! enoent

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.hXloa/_logs/2018-04-08T14_35_37_422Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

inside `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "4.1.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.66.0",
    "mobx": "^4.0.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "superagent": "^3.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .././app.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would try reinstalling react dependencies

Comment: Thats what i did. I completely removed them and reinstalled but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by deleting `package-lock.json` then pushing to `heroku`

Answer (score -1):

make sure that when you install all your react dependencies you saved it ex:

```
npm install --save redux
```

not

```
npm install redux
```